# What about an option to follow questions?

Tags: feature-request

Is there already a way to follow a question on Stack Overflow: further updates and answers, etc.? Or maybe it is on your future releases.

Answer (score 5):

Just click on the star symbol and then you can go to your profile page and see your favorite marked questions. See below:

[image]

Comment: not enough freehand circles for meta :/